# Python tkinter Button not responding

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

## TKINTER GRAPHICS

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()

btn = Button(tk, text="Click Me") #Makes a useless button

btn.pack() #Shows the button

import turtle #Makes the graphics work

t = turtle.Pen() 

def hello(): #Makes button not 
print('hello here')

btn = Button(tk, text="Click Me", command=hello)
```

The program SHOULD say `hello there` when I click the button, but I can't click the button because it won't respond.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: The second button never appears because you do not pack() it.  The first button appears, but does not call a function when clicked so "does not respond".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you appear to create the same button twice, once where it's ***not connected*** to a function but ***packed***, and once where it's ***connected*** to a function but ***not packed***.  If you combine the two, you'll get a working button.

But let's jump in and fix another problem before it begins -- you invoked:

```
t = turtle.Pen()
```

No, not when you're working within **tkinter**.  If you're working with turtle standalone, it's Turtle/Pen and Screen, but if you're working within tkinter, it's RawTurtle/RawPen and TurtleScreen.  Otherwise you end up with extra windows and potential root conflicts.

Combining all the above together, adding a scrolled canvas for the turtle to play on, and changing the `print()` to the console to be a `turtle.write()` to the scrolled canvas, we get:

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle # Makes the graphics work

def hello():  # Makes button not
    turtle.write('hello there', align='center', font=('Arial', 18, 'normal'))

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=hello)  # Makes a button
button.pack()  # Shows the button

canvas = turtle.ScrolledCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)

turtle = turtle.RawPen(screen, visible=False)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]